# Break in the list

Tags: lists, enumerate, labels, enumitem

I would like to continue my `enumerate` list.

But when I use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
\item Jeżeli będzie padać, bierzemy taksówkę. \\
(If it is raining, then we are taking a taxi.)

\item Gdyby było mi ciepło, zdjęłabym kurtkę. \\
(If i were warm, then I would remove my jacket.)
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Gdyby było mi ciepło, zdjęłabym kurtkę. \\
 (Were I warm, I would remove my jacket.)
\end{enumerate}

Innymi przykładami mogą być następujące zdania
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Kiedy spotkam dobrego człowieka, będę go chwalić. \\
(When I find a good man, I will praise him.)
\end{enumerate}
```

I lost previous style of list.

What I should do continuing style form previous list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `resume*`, not `resume`. The starred version uses the options given to the last list(s), the unstarred version discards any option that was not already specified in list definition.

Alternatively: Define a enumerate of your own (as shown in the example)

... and this is what the `enumitem` package suggests: Use `resume*` sparingly, define rather a new list ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\newlist{otherenum}{enumerate}{4}

\setlist[otherenum,1]{label={(\arabic*)}}

\begin{document}




\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
\item Jeżeli będzie padać, bierzemy taksówkę. \\
(If it is raining, then we are taking a taxi.)

\item Gdyby było mi ciepło, zdjęłabym kurtkę. \\
(If i were warm, then I would remove my jacket.)
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Gdyby było mi ciepło, zdjęłabym kurtkę. \\
 (Were I warm, I would remove my jacket.)
\end{enumerate}

Innymi przykładami mogą być następujące zdania
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Kiedy spotkam dobrego człowieka, będę go chwalić. \\
(When I find a good man, I will praise him.)
\end{enumerate}


With \verb!otherenum!: 


\begin{otherenum}
\item Jeżeli będzie padać, bierzemy taksówkę. \\
(If it is raining, then we are taking a taxi.)

\item Gdyby było mi ciepło, zdjęłabym kurtkę. \\
(If i were warm, then I would remove my jacket.)
\end{otherenum}

\begin{otherenum}[resume*]
\item Gdyby było mi ciepło, zdjęłabym kurtkę. \\
 (Were I warm, I would remove my jacket.)
\end{otherenum}

Innymi przykładami mogą być następujące zdania
\begin{otherenum}[resume*]
\item Kiedy spotkam dobrego człowieka, będę go chwalić. \\
(When I find a good man, I will praise him.)
\end{otherenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Saizou: You're welcome. Happy TeXing